# Removing variables based on average of a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, subset, average

I have a time series in R (in the example dataframe I created 1 to 5 seconds; in actuality it goes from -2 to 20 seconds). For each of these times I have a value for a variable (in the example SD1 and SD2; in actuality I have series of 49 values). I want to identify all variables that have an average value of < +5 and > - 5 from time 2 seconds to time 4 seconds. Once they are identified, I want to remove these values from the dataset but keep the rest of the time series in tact.

Example Dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(Participant = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B','B','B','C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C' ), 
                  Time = c(1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5), 
                  SD1 = c(-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,50, 50, 50,50,50,1,1, 1,1,1), 
                  SD2 = c(0, 50, 50, 50,0, 0,0,0,1,50, 0,0,0,1,50))
```

So I would end up with something like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Participant = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B','B','B','C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C' ), 
                  Time = c(1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5), 
                  SD1 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1, 1,1,1), 
                  SD2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 0,0,0,1,50, 0,0,0,1,50))
```

I appreciate any and all feedback on this issue!

Comment: Hi, the following isn't clear: "and > - 5 from time 2 seconds to time 4 seconds".

Comment: You wan to remove them or set them to `NA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the value `between` `Time` 2 and 4 seconds for each `Participant` and calculate their `mean`. Replace the values with `NA` if the mean is greater than 5. We can use `across` to apply the function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  mutate(across(SD1:SD2, ~if(abs(mean(.[between(Time, 2, 4)])) > 5) NA else .))

#   Participant  Time   SD1   SD2
#   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A               1    NA    NA
# 2 A               2    NA    NA
# 3 A               3    NA    NA
# 4 A               4    NA    NA
# 5 A               5    NA    NA
# 6 B               1    NA     0
# 7 B               2    NA     0
# 8 B               3    NA     0
# 9 B               4    NA     1
#10 B               5    NA    50
#11 C               1     1     0
#12 C               2     1     0
#13 C               3     1     0
#14 C               4     1     1
#15 C               5     1    50
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This worked perfectly! Take care!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following code works for you

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    lapply(split(df, df$Participant), function(v) {
      transform(v,
        SD1 = ifelse(all(abs(mean(SD1[Time >= 2 & Time <= 4])) <= 5),1,NA)*SD1,
        SD2 = ifelse(all(abs(mean(SD2[Time >= 2 & Time <= 4])) <= 5),1,NA)*SD2
      )
    })
  )
)
```

or

```
df %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  mutate(SD1 = ifelse(all(abs(mean(SD1[Time >= 2 & Time <= 4])) <= 5), 1, NA) * SD1) %>%
  mutate(SD2 = ifelse(all(abs(mean(SD2[Time >= 2 & Time <= 4])) <= 5), 1, NA) * SD2)
```

both are giving

```
   Participant Time SD1 SD2
1            A    1  NA  NA
2            A    2  NA  NA
3            A    3  NA  NA
4            A    4  NA  NA
5            A    5  NA  NA
6            B    1  NA   0
7            B    2  NA   0
8            B    3  NA   0
9            B    4  NA   1
10           B    5  NA  50
11           C    1   1   0
12           C    2   1   0
13           C    3   1   0
14           C    4   1   1
15           C    5   1  50
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I went with the code above so I did not have to write out each SD pair but I greatly appreciate your help!